# Calculator will not answer new problems

Tags: java, jpanel, jlabel

The calculator I am working on will solve the first problem perfectly, but when add is hit a second time, the answer moves closer to the addends and both the addends and the sum remain the same. Can anyone shine some light on what is making my program act this way? Thanks!

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

private JTextField field1;
private JTextField field2;
private JButton add, subtract, multiply, divide;
private JLabel lanswer, label1, label2;
private String input1, input2, sanswer;
private int answer = 0;

JPanel contentPanel, answerPanel;

public GUI(){
    super("Calculator");

    field1 = new JTextField(null, 15);
    field2 = new JTextField(null, 15);

    add = new JButton("add");
    subtract = new JButton("subtract");
    multiply = new JButton("multiply");
    divide = new JButton("divide");

    lanswer = new JLabel("", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    label1 = new JLabel("Value 1:");
    label2 = new JLabel("Value 2:");

    add.addActionListener(this);

    Dimension opSize = new Dimension(110, 20);
    Dimension inSize = new Dimension(200, 20);

    lanswer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,255));

    field1.setPreferredSize(inSize);
    field2.setPreferredSize(inSize);
    add.setPreferredSize(opSize);
    subtract.setPreferredSize(opSize);
    multiply.setPreferredSize(opSize);
    divide.setPreferredSize(opSize);

    contentPanel = new JPanel();
    contentPanel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    contentPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    answerPanel = new JPanel();
    answerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(230, 260));
    answerPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    answerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(answerPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    contentPanel.add(answerPanel);
    contentPanel.add(label1); contentPanel.add(field1); 
    contentPanel.add(label2); contentPanel.add(field2);
    contentPanel.add(add); contentPanel.add(subtract); contentPanel.add(multiply); contentPanel.add(divide);


    this.setContentPane(contentPanel);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton src = (JButton)e.getSource();

    if(src.equals(add)){
        add();
    } 
}

private void add(){
    input1 = field1.getText();
    input2 = field2.getText();

    MathEquation problem = new MathEquation(input1, input2);

    Dimension lineSize = new Dimension(200, 10);

    JPanel line1 = new JPanel(); line1.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
    line1.setPreferredSize(lineSize);
    JPanel line2 = new JPanel(); line2.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
    line2.setPreferredSize(lineSize);
    JPanel line3 = new JPanel(); line3.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
    line3.setPreferredSize(lineSize);
    JPanel line4 = new JPanel(); line4.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 
    line4.setPreferredSize(lineSize);
    JPanel line5 = new JPanel(); line5.setBackground(Color.WHITE); 

    JLabel[] sumLabels = problem.getSumLabels();
    JLabel[] addend1Labels = problem.getAddend1Labels();
    JLabel[] addend2Labels = problem.getAddend2Labels();
    JLabel[] carriedLabels = problem.getCarriedLabels();

    for(int i = 0; i < carriedLabels.length; i++){
        line1.add(carriedLabels[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < addend1Labels.length; i++){
        line2.add(addend1Labels[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < addend2Labels.length; i++){
        line3.add(addend2Labels[i]);
    }

    String answerLine = "__";

    for(int i = 0; i < sumLabels.length; i++){
        answerLine += "__";
    }

    line4.add(new JLabel(answerLine));

    for(int i = 0; i < sumLabels.length; i++){
        line5.add(sumLabels[i]);
    }

    answerPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
    answerPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
    answerPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
    answerPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
    answerPanel.add(line1);
    answerPanel.add(line1);
    answerPanel.add(line2);
    answerPanel.add(line3);
    answerPanel.add(line4);
    answerPanel.add(line5);
    answerPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
    answerPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
    answerPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
    answerPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));

    this.setContentPane(contentPanel);
    this.revalidate();
}

private String subtract(){
    input1 = field1.getText();
    input2 = field2.getText();
    answer = Integer.parseInt(input1) - Integer.parseInt(input2);

    sanswer = "<html><p align='right'>" + input1 + "<br>-+";

    if(input1.length() >= input2.length()){
        for(int i = 0; i < input1.length() - input2.length() + 1; i++){
            sanswer+="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
    }

    sanswer += input2 + "<br>";

    if(input1.length() >= input2.length()){
        for(int i = 0; i < input1.length(); i++){
            sanswer+="--";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < input2.length(); i++){
            sanswer+="--";
        }
    }



    sanswer += "<br>" + answer + "</p></html>";

    return sanswer;

}

private String multiply(){
    input1 = field1.getText();
    input2 = field2.getText();
    answer = Integer.parseInt(input1) * Integer.parseInt(input2);

    sanswer = "<html><p align='right'>" + input1 + "<br>x";

    if(input1.length() >= input2.length()){
        for(int i = 0; i < input1.length() - input2.length() + 1; i++){
            sanswer+="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
    }

    sanswer += input2 + "<br>";

    if(input1.length() >= input2.length()){
        for(int i = 0; i < input1.length(); i++){
            sanswer+="--";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < input2.length(); i++){
            sanswer+="--";
        }
    }



    sanswer += "<br>" + answer + "</p></html>";

    return sanswer;

}
}
```

MathEquation:

```
 public class MathEquation {

private ArrayList<Character> addend1, addend2, sum, carried;

public MathEquation(String a, String b){

    setAddends(a, b);
    findSum();

    System.out.println(carried.toString());
    System.out.println("   "+addend1.toString());
    System.out.println("   "+addend2.toString());
    System.out.println("   "+sum.toString());

}

public JLabel[] getAddend1Labels(){

    Dimension addendSize = new Dimension(10,10);
    JLabel[] getAddend1 = new JLabel[addend1.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < addend1.size(); i++){
        getAddend1[i] = new JLabel(addend1.get(i).toString());
        getAddend1[i].setPreferredSize(addendSize);
    }

    return getAddend1;

}

public JLabel[] getAddend2Labels(){

    Dimension addendSize = new Dimension(10,10);
    JLabel[] getAddend2 = new JLabel[addend2.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < addend2.size(); i++){
        getAddend2[i] = new JLabel(addend2.get(i).toString());
        getAddend2[i].setPreferredSize(addendSize);
    }

    return getAddend2;

}

public JLabel[] getSumLabels(){

    Dimension sumSize = new Dimension(10,10);
    JLabel[] getSum = new JLabel[sum.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < sum.size(); i++){
        getSum[i] = new JLabel(sum.get(i).toString());
        getSum[i].setPreferredSize(sumSize);
    }

    return getSum;

}

public JLabel[] getCarriedLabels(){

    Dimension carriedSize = new Dimension(10,10);
    JLabel[] getCarried = new JLabel[carried.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < carried.size(); i++){
        getCarried[i] = new JLabel(carried.get(i).toString());
        getCarried[i].setPreferredSize(carriedSize);
    }

    return getCarried;

}

public void setAddends(String a, String b){

    char[] arrayA = a.toCharArray();
    char[] arrayB = b.toCharArray();

    addend1 = new ArrayList<Character>();
    addend2 = new ArrayList<Character>();

    ArrayList wholeA = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList wholeB = new ArrayList();

    boolean wholeNumber = true;

    ArrayList decimalA = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList decimalB = new ArrayList();

    int decALength = 0, decBLength = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++){

        if(arrayA[i] != '.'){

            addend1.add(arrayA[i]);

            if(wholeNumber){

                wholeA.add(arrayA[i]);

            } else {

                decimalA.add(arrayA[i]);

            }

        } else {

            addend1.add(arrayA[i]);
            wholeNumber = false;    
            decALength = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayA, i+1, arrayA.length).length;
            System.out.println(decALength);
        }

    }

    wholeNumber = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++){

        if(arrayB[i] != '.'){

            addend2.add(arrayB[i]);

            if(wholeNumber){

                wholeB.add(arrayB[i]);

            } else {

                decimalB.add(arrayB[i]);

            }

            } else {

                addend2.add(arrayB[i]);
                wholeNumber = false;    
                decBLength = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayB, i+1, arrayB.length).length;
                System.out.println(decBLength);
            }

    }

    if(decALength>decBLength){
        if(decBLength==0){
            addend2.add('.');
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < decALength-decBLength; i++){
            addend2.add('0');
        }
    } else if(decBLength>decALength){
        if(decALength==0){
            addend1.add('.');
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < decBLength-decALength; i++){
            addend1.add('0');
        }
    }

    if(wholeA.size() < wholeB.size())
        for(int i = 0; i < wholeB.size()-wholeA.size(); i++)
            addend1.add(0, '0');
    else if(wholeA.size() > wholeB.size())
        for(int i = 0; i < wholeA.size()-wholeB.size(); i++)
            addend2.add(0, '0');

    addend1.add(0, '0');
    addend2.add(0, '0');
}

private void findSum(){

    sum = new ArrayList<Character>();
    carried = new ArrayList<Character>();
    int dec = 0;

    carried.add('0');

    for(int i = addend1.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){

        if(addend1.get(i) != '.'){
            int a = Character.getNumericValue(addend1.get(i));
            int b = Character.getNumericValue(addend2.get(i));
            int c = Character.getNumericValue(carried.get(carried.size()-1));
            int d = a + b + c;

            if(d >= 10){
                carried.add('1');
                d-=10;
                sum.add((char) ('0' + d));
            } else {

                carried.add('0');
                sum.add((char) ('0' + d));

            } 

        } else {

            sum.add('.');
            carried.add(carried.size()-1, ' ');
        } 

    }

    Collections.reverse(sum);
    Collections.reverse(carried);

    carried.remove(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < carried.size(); i++){
        if(carried.get(i) == '0'){
            carried.set(i, ' ');
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < addend1.size(); i++){
        if(addend1.get(i) == '0'){
            addend1.set(i, ' ');
        }
        else break;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < addend2.size(); i++){
        if(addend2.get(i) == '0'){
            addend2.set(i, ' ');
        }
        else break;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < sum.size(); i++){
        if(sum.get(i) == '0'){
            sum.set(i, ' ');
        }
        else break;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there seems to be a lot of missing code like `MathEquation`. and I haven't a clue what your calculator's `answerPanel` might look like. Having said that, a wild guess would be that `getSumLabels()` returns the previous results; you perhaps require a `resetSumLabels()` method to reinitialise them.

Comment: I will add math equation

Comment: Thank you. One thing to check is `int a = Character.getNumericValue(addend1.get(i))`. I think second time around you have replaced leading zeros with space characters, so the code might be setting `a` and `b` to `-1`?

Comment: The addition works fine.